# Определите модуль разницы между средними значениями

Tags: python, pandas

Необходимо определить модуль разницы между средними тратами женщин и мужчин (трата - отрицательное значение amount). (*)

Пояснения:

(*) Если в результате для мужчин получились значения [-1,-3,-5], а для женщин [-1,-2,-3], то модуль разницы между средними арифметическими -3 и -2 будет равен 1.

(**) Обратите внимание, что для вычисления модуля разности точных знаний о том,
какой класc относится к мужчинам, а какой - к женщинам, пока не требуется.

(***) Округление не нужно производить отдельно по средним тратам женщин и мужчин, а только в самом конце, когда получите значение модуля разницы трат.

Правильно ли я понял, что сначала я определяю траты (т.е. значения меньше 0) у мужчин и женщин потом нахожу среднее значения и затем считаю модуль этих средних?

Как посчитать модуль средних?

Фрейм данных такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мое решение:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
 %matplotlib inline

 df_3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\ееее.csv', sep=',')
 groups=df_3.groupby(['gender']) # отфильтровал по полу
 groups.ngroups # сколько видов по полу
 gg_1 = groups.get_group(0) # отфильтровал по полу 0
 gg_1_traty = gg_1.loc[(gg_1['amount'] < 0)] # нашел траты со знаком -
 gg_1_traty_sred = gg_1_traty.amount.mean() # средние траты для пола 0
```

Тоже самое для второго пола.

А дальше что, не понимаю как посчитать модуль среднего значения трат мужчин и женщин.

Comment: Никогда не давайте в вопросе данные как картинку. Это многих раздражает и вы рискуете, что вообще не получите ответа, а только насобираете минусов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как-то так:

```
res = df_3.groupby("gender")["amount"].mean().diff().abs()
```

**NOTE:** данное решение не тестировалось по причине отсутсвия в вопросе воспроизводимого примера данных.

PS на будущее - советую оформлять вопросы так, как показано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

```
# несколько баз открыты и сшиты  в один датафрейм task1

task1_minus = task1[task1.amount <0]   
# отбираем только траты , они с минусом
task1_minus.amount = task1_minus.amount*(-1)   
# меняем их знак, чтоб модуль не использовать
task1_minus_11 = task1_minus[task1_minus.gender == 1.0] 
# выборка по мужчинам
task1_minus_01 = task1_minus[task1_minus.gender == 0.0] 
# выборка по женщинам
rezz0 = round((task1_minus_11.amount.mean() -task1_minus_01.amount.mean()),2)  
# делаем разницу и округляем
rezz0
```